# Is my proof correct?(Proving convergence of the $\sum f'(n)$ )

Tags: real-analysis

$Q)$ Let differentiable $f : [0,\infty) \to \mathbb{R} $ satisfying  the conditions.

$(1)$ $f'$ is decreasing on $[0,\infty)$ and $f'(x) >0$,$ \forall x \in [0,\infty)$

$(2)$ $f $ is a bounded on $[0,\infty)$

Show  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f'(n)$  is convergent. (Hint :  $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f(n+1) - f(n)$)

---

Though my book suggested the solution, But I tried different way. Here is the my trial.

By Mean value thm, $\exists C_n \in (n,n+1)$ $s.t.$ $f'(C_n) = f(n+1) - f(n)$

Plus by the condition $(1)$, $f'(n)> f'(C_n) > f'(n+1)$

Then, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f'(n) = f'(1)+\sum_{n=2}^{\infty} f'(n) < f'(1)+\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f'(C_n)$

Here the $f'(C_n)(>0)$ is decreasing to $0 $

We can conclude $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f'(C_n) = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int_{2}^{n} f'(x) dx = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} f(n)-f(2) <M-f(2)$

(since the  $f$ is bounded, I.e. $f(x) < M$)

Therefore, $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} f'(n)$ is convergent.

Is my proof right? Though I used integral test for the series, I have a doubt of the correctness because it only makes sense $f(n)$, Not the $f(C_n)$ (since $C_n$ is not natural number). Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost right but you have to be more careful in applying the integral test. We have $\int_n^{n+1} f'(t)dt \geq f'(n+1) \geq f'(C_{n+1})$. Since $\int_2^{\infty} f'(t)dt <\infty$ we see that $\sum f'(C_{n+1}) <\infty$. But this implies that $\sum f'(C_n) <\infty$ since these two series differ only by one term. Finally this implies $\sum f'(n) <\infty$.

Comment: How would you justify the integrability of $f'$ though?

Comment: @DodoDuQuercy OP has already shown integrability of $f'$ so I didn't bother to write it again.

Answer (score 1):

You have to be careful because you cannot necessarily integrate $f'$.

You had the right idea though. Here is how I would do to make it rigorous:

Let $n \geq 1$. $f$ is continuous on $[n-1,n]$ and differentiable on $]n-1,n[$ so by mean value theorem there exists $C_n \in ]n-1,n[$ such that $f(n) - f(n-1) = f'(C_n)$. Therefore, since $f'$ is decreasing, we have

$$
f'(n) \leq f'(C_n) = f(n) - f(n-1).
$$

As a result, for all $N$,

$$
\sum_{n=1}^N f'(n) \leq \sum_{n=1}^N [f(n) - f(n-1)] = f(N) - f(0).
$$

Since $f$ is bounded, there exists $M$ such that $\forall x \in [0,+\infty[,f(x) \leq M$.

Therefore

$$
\sum_{n=1}^N f'(n) \leq M - f(0).
$$

Since all $f'(n)$ are positive and the partial sums of the series are bounded, the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty f'(n)$ converges by monotone convergence.

Comment: Note: if you are concerned with that, this method has the 'advantage' of not using the axiom of choice that is used in Kavi Rama Murthy's answer when considering the $C_n$'s all together rather than seperately. Of course, the majority of mathematicians assume the axiome of choice so there is no problem with using it, but I find it nice to know whether you need it or not in a proof

Comment: Fair answer! Terrific! Thanks for leading me another way. :)

Comment: No pb, glad to help!

Comment: Your comments on Axiom of Choice do not make sense. Very unfair comments and unfair downvoting.

Comment: Please explain me why they do not make sense then, I am open to dialogue. How does your solution not involve the countable axiom of choice? But as I said, using it is not a problem, I think the problem with your answer is that you didn't provide arguments for why the integral of $f’$ is well defined. Please provide an answer for that and I will be glad to cancel my downvote